# Is it possible to post to pages that you are an admin for using the Facebook Javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am able to write on my own wall but not on the wall of pages I am an admin for.  I am using the code below (Javascript SDK):

```
         FB.ui(
           {
             method: 'stream.publish',
             message: 'getting educated about Facebook Connect',
             attachment: {
               name: 'Connect',
               caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
               description: (
                 'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
                 'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
                 'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
               ),
               href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js'
             },
             action_links: [
               { text: 'Code', href: 'http://github.com/facebook/connect-js' }
             ],
             user_message_prompt: 'Share your thoughts about Connect',
             target_id: '170500829645508',
             uid: '100001920038281'
           },
           function(response) {
             if (response && response.post_id) {
               alert('Post was published.');
             } else {
               alert('Post was not published.');
             }
           }
         );
         }
```

Where target ID is the page I admin and uid is my account user id.  When I run this code I keep getting the error message:

> An invalid target was specified:
>   170500829645508. The target must be a page, event, or user that the actor
>   can post on the wall of.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this method which works for posting to a page that I admin.  Haven't figured out how to include attachments this way though...

```
     var wallPost = {
        access_token: ".........................",
        message: 'Here is some more stuff'
    };

    FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', wallPost, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occurred:' +  response.error.message);
        } else {
            alert('Success!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the manage_pages extended permission to do this. Once the permission is granted you can query graph.facebook.com/me/accounts to retrieve an API token that can post to a page's wall. Check out Facebook's extended permissions here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions.

Comment: Ok, I think i have the token i need.  Now what do I do with it?